# How should be folder structure while nodeJs app in general

Tags: node.js, github, hosting, web-hosting, netlify

Recently I tried to host my project in netlify using GitHub repo. But the website is not running properly

This is my folder structure

```
esports 
--views 
----index.Pug 
----afterSubmit.pug 
--node_modules 
--static 
----style.css 
--app.js 
--package.Json
```

Haven't used any gitignore file also. I'm a newbie to GitHub and webhosting.

Even I tried to change the pug file back to html and placed it outside.

new folder structure

```
--views 
--node_modules 
--public 
----style.css 
--src ----app.js
--index.html 
--afterSubmit.html 
--package.Json
```

I don't have much idea about the packages required for hosting

Comment: Aren't you suppose to compile node code for production first?

Comment: I'm not into any production-level projects. I tried to host my website using Netlify which I found a problem with. I think I should use a VPS for hosting